# Server Error in '/' Application while accessing Admin Panel in Joomla Site on IIS Server 8

Tags: php, joomla, iis-8

I am setting up a Joomla site on Windows Server IIS 8 but when I try to access its admin panel through below link :

```
http://localhost/site_name/administrator
```

It throws below error always
[image: Error Image]

I don't know why it is throwing error of login.aspx when I am running a php site.

So please help me out.

Comment: How did you install joomla?

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla, you have to add path entry in config.php files in both admin and front end. Maybe you have missed one in admin.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting permissions to the project folder.

Thanks for everyone.